# ASP.NET Core - Do not open the page by entering the address in the browser?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have three actions that open in stages... The actions are as follows?

```
https://localhost:44336/Login
https://localhost:44336/Register
https://localhost:44336/Active
```

First the login page opens, then the active page, then the registration page.

I used viewbag to prevent these URLs from being opened directly

```
public IActionResult Activate()
{
    if (ViewBag.Mobile == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View();
}
```

This has a problem when I refresh the page out of action!

Is there a way to do this without a viewbag? If the user enters the address in the browser, the page will not open, but if it is refreshed, it will not leave the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement can be solved by Autentication.I wrote a demo about cookie Authenticantion in asp.net core .you could also try other methods like jwt.

Codes in your startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

        .......

           services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, m =>
                {
                    m.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Users/Login");
                    m.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Home/Privacy");
                    m.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
        .......

        }

........



 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

           ........

           app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

          .......

         }
```

Codes in your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
        {
               ........
            var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Name),new Claim("Mobile",user.Mobile)};
            var userPricipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Customer"));
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPricipal, new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),//you could set the time of cookie here
                IsPersistent = false,
                AllowRefresh = false
            });
            var mobile = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == user.Name && m.Mobile == user.Mobile).Mobile;

            if (user.Mobile != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
           ..........
            return View();
        }
```

Add the [Authorize] Attribute on the Action that needs Authentication:

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

you could read the offical document for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0